# Django: How not to reload the entire page on just a few content updates?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I am using Django as my Web Framework.
I want to update the content of a page when the user clicks a button.
Is it possible to not update the entire page?

For example, if I wanted to program a todo list. Then I would not want to reload the whole page when adding an item at the bottom.

Is there a solution for just updating the updatet elements?

In my example code below it is unfortunately so that the entire page is reloaded every time

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context = {
            'results': 'Some kind of result',
        }
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
    return render(request, 'users/register.html')
```

Comment: You are searching for the term [tag:ajax]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax if you don't want the whole page to be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use Ajax for this purpose.

It is so easy and found in all websites now a-days.